# Xcode interface error, expected method body

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have copied an ios project from one machine to mine , i am getting two errors

1. Missing context for method declaration
2. Expected method body

I have checked the search path, its all fine. also implemetnation file contains method.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h>

@interface HumeApiClient : AFHTTPSessionManager

+(HumeApiClient *)SharedClient;
-(void)AddAccessTokenInHeader;

@end


@implementation HumeApiClient


+(HumeApiClient *)SharedClient
{
    static HumeApiClient *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedClient = [[self alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"defaultUrl"]]];

    });
    return sharedClient;
}


-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    self.requestSerializer =  [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    return self;
}


-(void)AddAccessTokenInHeader{

    [self.requestSerializer setValue: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:ACCESSTOKEN] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Access_Token"];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing implementation of your interface, see following as an example:

```
@interface SampleClass:NSObject
/* method declaration */
- (int)max:(int)num1 andNum2:(int)num2;
@end

@implementation SampleClass

/* method returning the max between two numbers */
- (int)max:(int)num1 andNum2:(int)num2 {

   /* local variable declaration */
   int result;

   if (num1 > num2) {
      result = num1;
   } else {
      result = num2;
   }

   return result; 
}
```

Comment: Implementation file is already there, i am getting thes two errors in this file

Comment: Can you provide it? - just the signatures should be fine

Comment: This looks fine, what about the .h file? Can you provide it?

Comment: .h file is one which is called inteface and.m implementation

Comment: and you copied all content of those files? There are no cyclic imports etc?

Comment: actually client provided this source code, adding libraries without ticking copy all items can lead to error?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments I understand that both the .h and .m files are represented in the question.
To work correctly, they should look like this:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h>

@interface HumeApiClient : AFHTTPSessionManager

+(HumeApiClient *)SharedClient;
-(void)AddAccessTokenInHeader;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "HumeApiClient.h"

@interface HumeApiClient()
@end

@implementation HumeApiClient

+(HumeApiClient *)SharedClient {
     [...]
}


-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    [...]
}


-(void)AddAccessTokenInHeader{
    [...]
}
@end
```

This way it should work.

Moreover, I'd suggest you don't capitalize the names of your methods.

Comment: ../../../AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h - Expected identifier or '(' .

Comment: Replace "#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h>" with @import AFNetworking; (this works for me - but I've installed it as a pod, so I'm not 100% sure it also works in other environments)